# Revive Ad on Google AMP

Tags: html, css, ads, amp-html

I'm going through the Google AMP tutorial and I've also done some research on this question with no luck.

We're using a Revive Ad server to render text and image ads on our site. It appears that Revive may not be compatible with AMP but I'm not completely sure. Does anyone know how to integrate Revive with Google AMP? Here is the example code that Google provides for adding an ad (DoubleClick).

```
<amp-ad
  width="300"
  height="250"
  type="doubleclick"
  data-slot="/35096353/amptesting/image/static">
</amp-ad>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can serve ads in AMP pages with the Revive server, make sure you ad sandbox settings to your iframe tag if that's what you use and also serve the ads over SSL (https). We use ad inserter and wordpress AMP. Works like a charm.

```
<iframe id='a9ca6757' name='a9ca6757' src='https://<YOURDMAIN>/delivery/afr.php?n=a9ca6757&amp;zoneid=101&amp;target=_blank&amp;cb=764566425' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' width='300' height='250' sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-same-origin"><a href='https://<YOURDMAIN>/delivery/ck.php?n=af3707ff&amp;cb=764566425' target='_blank'><img src='https://<YOURDMAIN>/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=101&amp;cb=764566425&amp;n=af3707ff' border='0' alt='' /></a></iframe>
```

Comment: This is only workaround. You can't place this code on top of page, even on the middle of page. As of rules of google